# How to select a span inside a div?

Tags: css, class, html

I'm having an issue coloring a span with css. Everything is working fine on the webpage however when I try to select a span in a div it doesn't work. Am I missing something dumb here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="style/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src= https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js></script>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </header>

    <main>  
        <div class = "tab1 triad">
            <script src="primejs.js"></script>

            <span class="red"><h2>Type in a number and I'll check if it is prime:</h2></span>

            <input class = "primeNum" type = "text">
            <button class = "submit">Submit</button>

            <span class = "result">
                <h2>What I found: <span class = "answer">?</span></h2>
            </span>
        </div>  
    </main> 
</body>
```

and here is the css:

```
.tab1 span.red {
    color: RED;
    font-size: 100;
}
```

Comment: You have invalid HTML. Fix that first, and then it appears it should work correctly. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6FpH/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @user, well, you're styling the spans, not the h2s. Are you sure there is no higher priority style that can affect them?

Comment: @j08691, I (and most browsers) have seen worse.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Your point being?

Comment: where is the invalid html? This is just a snippit of the code

Comment: @j08691, that "invalid" HTML is not the problem here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - sure isn't helping anything.

Comment: @user41829, take a look at the JSFiddle I provided, and compare it to the HTML you provided. (In other terms: the `</h2>` after the `</button>` tag is invalid.  You must use closing tags in the inner-most order (ex. if you have an opening `p` tag and then an opening `b` tag, you must close the `b` tag before the `p` tag. It's proper HTML)

Comment: Ok i removed it and it doesn't fix the problem. So thats not the issue here

Comment: I added the full code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cleaned up your HTML, you had a some stray and missing tags.

[Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/jaguwuci/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div class="tab1 triad">
  <span class="red">
    <h2>Type in a number and I'll check if it is prime:</h2>
  </span>

  <input class="primeNum" type="text">
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>

  <span class="result">
    <h2>What I found: <span class="answer">?</span></h2>
  </span>
</div>
```

And your css was missing the px after 100

```
.tab1 span.red {
  color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: If the text is still not red and at 100px, then there is an error elsewhere. Have you looked at the JSBin link user3546438 provided?

Comment: Yeah I posted my full code above. There should be no problems unless I'm missing something small. I've stripped out anything that could be causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.red {
    color: red;
    font-size: 100px; /* specify a unit like px, em, ... */
}
```

Comment: and erase that <h2> that's invalid

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely clear. Maybe use an actual CSS comment for the note, and give units in the example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the HTML code you have posted is not valid. You can use the [official W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check if you like. The main issue is the spaces either side of your `=` when declaring attributes. Spaces are only ever used in between different attributes. Also, `h2` elements are block type elements, and are therefore not allowed inside of an inline element (e.g., `span`).

Secondly, the CSS is also not all valid. Firstly, there is no need to make anything uppercase, as is shown for the colour name. `color:red;` will work just fine. Also, you have not specified any units of measurement for the `font-size` property. I assume you intended for the text to be at 100pt, in which case you need to use `font-size:100pt;`. Other valid units of measurement include `px`, `cm` and `rem`.

I recommend you read information on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for examples if you would like to learn more. It includes accurate pages about HTML elements, CSS properties and JavaScript.

**Edit:**

The following would help to fix the HTML:

- Change `doctype` to `DOCTYPE`, which improves compatibility.
- Move all `script` tags into the `head` tag.
- Ensure that all `input`s, `button`s, etc. are inside of `form` elements.
- Remove spaces around `=` signs.
- Make the `href` attribute of the stylesheet `link` tag the second attribute, and make the `rel` attribute the first. This is primarily for consistency.

Comment: I know there are mistakes like this but fixing all of these don't make a difference it still doesn't display the font as red

Comment: @user41829 Can you tell us more about your setup? Are you viewing the file in a browser from your hard-drive or using a local webserver? Also check that the URL for the stylesheet is valid. Is the CSS saved as `mainstyle.css` in a folder called `style`, that is in the same folder as the HTML?